# Issue with Django Internationalization

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I am using Django internationalization for the first time. I have go through the docs and do the same but no result.

My folder structure is like

```
mysite
    manage.py
    main
      __init__.py
      views.py
      models.py
      tests.py
    mysite
      __init__.py
      settings.py
      views.py
      urls.py
      wsgi.py
    templates
       base.html
    locale
       en
        LC_MESSAGES
          django.mo
          django.po
       fr
        LC_MESSAGES
          django.mo
          django.po
```

My settings.py is like :

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('fr', 'French'),
)
from django.conf import global_settings
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + \
     ('django.core.context_processors.i18n',)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    'D:\mysite\locale'    
)

USE_I18N = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',    
 )
```

My views.py is like :

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader


def home(request):
   template = loader.get_template('base.html')
   context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_question_list': '',
   })
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

And my templates/base.html is like :

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "Hello World" %}
```

Inside the `fr` folder under `locale` in `django.po` i have added

```
#: .\django\conf\global_settings.py:74
msgid "French"
msgstr "Bonjour tout le monde"
```

I tried to change the firefox content from tools and tried to add french language and reload the page, but not working. Can anyone help me what the mistake i am making . Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same problem long time back. This should work for you. After your changes to django.po file, you need to do the following.

1. Generate mo file by using command compilemessages
2. Restart apache service.

Comment: no luck  after restarting the service. Already created the mo files using `django-admin.py compilemessages -l` . If the set up is fine for Internationalization ?